# How can I remove all SVG elements which do not intersect a particular rectangle?

Tags: svg

I have an SVG image from which I'd like to extract several rectangular regions as independent SVG images. Because the original image is rather large but the elements intersecting the areas of interest are small, I do not want elements which lie entirely outside the cropped `viewBox` to remain in the cropped SVG image.

Conceptually, what I'm looking for is this:

[image: cropping diagram]

The cropped SVG (yes, the output must be *SVG*, not a bitmap) should not contain elements for the spiral or the star, as they fall entirely outside the area of interest. (Yes, the nonintersecting elements really must be removed, due to the source SVG being several orders of magnitude more bytes than the cropped SVG, as I intend to crop the source in different ways hundreds of times.) I want to be able to specify the area of interest on the command-line, as well, due to having quite a number of such cropped images to produce.

Are there any tools which can do this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a mask? Or am I misunderstanding the issue?

Comment: Adding a mask won't remove the elements which fall wholly outside the area of interest. In my example, that would only be two elements, but in the SVG on which I want to operate, the ratio of elements to remove to elements to keep is at least 1000:1. I don't want to drag into the cropped images megabytes of elements which you can't see to get the ten kilobytes which you can see.

Comment: Iterate across your elements with getBBox, and compare x,y,width,height to see if there's overlap (it may not select quite all the shapes that don't overlap, but most of them). Then remove the overlapping elements. (If you're using filters that overflow the source area then this won't be quite accurate either)

Comment: Iterate across my elements with getBBox _in what_?

Comment: The problem is situated in a non-browser environment. To that effect a general purpose solution would be appreciated. @Michael Mullany, how would you address transformations in your proposed method?

Comment: Use phantom.js from the command line. To capture transformations, use getBoundingClientRect() instead of getBBox. It doesn't quite capture the minimal box, aka, it might include a small number of objects that are not in the selection area, but it should eliminate the vast majority

Answer (score 0):

SVG elements can be parsed and flagged true/false as inside a svg rect object and/or intersecting the rect object.
Would this work for you?

```
isEnclosed = mySVG.checkEnclosure(myElement, RectObj)
doesIntersect = mySVG.checkIntersection(myElement, RectObj)
```

Comment: this seems a promising ansatz (in general). Would it be possible to formulate it without using DOM specific events? Is there a reference implementation for the enclosure criteria? Esp. concerning arbitrarily complex nested nodes; what about transformations?

Comment: I checkd tranformations and yes it will operate on the screen x,y values. As for non DOM I have no idea. However, If you were working with only polygons, you could use the Sutherland-Hodgman clipping algorithm.

Comment: If we assume that the clipping mask is a rect registered to the global coordinate system, a Cohen–Sutherland might suffice. I wonder if it would be worth it to use a space partition tree?

Comment: I often use that approach when I zoom into an svg image: Elements outside the 'window' have their display turned to "none". I use the center point of each element's bounding box as the target value.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Jordan Curve Theorem to test for points inside an svg polygon. Your polygon would be your viewBox. Posssibly this could work for you if each element has a target point associated with it(i.e. center point) to determine if you want to show it or not.
The following is the javascript I use:(caution: I think the polygon should have counter-clockwise points. Always a good idea when dealing with polygons)

```
//---Point-in-polygon: Jordan Curve Theorem---
function pointInPolygon(myPolygon,px,py)
{
    var pointsList=myPolygon.points

    var x
    var y
    var x1
    var y1
    var crossings=0
    var verts=pointsList.numberOfItems

//---Iterate through each line ---
    for ( var i = 0; i < verts; i++ )
    {
        var vertx=pointsList.getItem(i).x
        var verty=pointsList.getItem(i).y
        if(i<verts-1)
        {
            var vertxNext=pointsList.getItem(i+1).x
            var vertyNext=pointsList.getItem(i+1).y
        }
        else
        {
            var vertxNext=pointsList.getItem(0).x
            var vertyNext=pointsList.getItem(0).y
        }

    /* This is done to ensure that we get the same result when
       the line goes from left to right and right to left */
        if ( vertx < vertxNext){
            x1 = vertx;
            x2 = vertxNext;
        } else {
            x1 = vertxNext;
            x2 = vertx;
        }

        /* First check if the ray is possible to cross the line */
        if ( px > x1 && px <= x2 && ( py < verty || py <= vertyNext ) ) {
        var eps = 0.000000001;

        /* Calculate the equation of the line */
        var dx = vertxNext - vertx;
        var dy = vertyNext - verty;
        var k;

        if ( Math.abs(dx) < eps ){
            k = Infinity;
        } else {
            k = dy/dx;
        }

            var m = verty - k * vertx;

            /* Find if the ray crosses the line */
            y2 = k * px + m;
            if ( py <= y2 ){
                crossings++;
            }
        }
    }
    //---odd number of crossings: point inside polygon--
    var crossFlag=(crossings/2)+""
    if(crossFlag.indexOf(".")!=-1)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your svg elements are transformed, you may need to convert them to screen points. I've used the following javascript for the various svg elements(line, rect, circle, ellipse, polygon, polyline, and path)

```
//----build a generic document SVG root to hold svg point---
function screenLine(line,svg)
{
    var sCTM = line.getCTM()
    var x1=parseFloat(line.getAttribute("x1"))
    var y1=parseFloat(line.getAttribute("y1"))
    var x2=parseFloat(line.getAttribute("x2"))
    var y2=parseFloat(line.getAttribute("y2"))

    var mySVGPoint1 = svg.createSVGPoint();
    mySVGPoint1.x = x1
    mySVGPoint1.y = y1
    mySVGPointTrans1 = mySVGPoint1.matrixTransform(sCTM)
    line.setAttribute("x1",mySVGPointTrans1.x)
    line.setAttribute("y1",mySVGPointTrans1.y)

    var mySVGPoint2 = svg.createSVGPoint();
    mySVGPoint2.x = x2
    mySVGPoint2.y = y2
    mySVGPointTrans2= mySVGPoint2.matrixTransform(sCTM)
    line.setAttribute("x2",mySVGPointTrans2.x)
    line.setAttribute("y2",mySVGPointTrans2.y)
    //---force removal of transform--
    line.setAttribute("transform","")
    line.removeAttribute("transform")
}
function screenCircle(circle,svg)
{
    var sCTM = circle.getCTM()
    var scaleX  = sCTM.a;

    var cx=parseFloat(circle.getAttribute("cx"))
    var cy=parseFloat(circle.getAttribute("cy"))

    var r=parseFloat(circle.getAttribute("r"))

    var mySVGPointC = svg.createSVGPoint();
    mySVGPointC.x = cx
    mySVGPointC.y = cy
    mySVGPointTransC = mySVGPointC.matrixTransform(sCTM)
    circle.setAttribute("cx",mySVGPointTransC.x)
    circle.setAttribute("cy",mySVGPointTransC.y)

    circle.setAttribute("r",r*scaleX)
    //---force removal of transform--
    circle.setAttribute("transform","")
    circle.removeAttribute("transform")
}
function screenEllipse(ellipse,svg)
{
    var sCTM = ellipse.getCTM()
    var scaleX  = sCTM.a;
    var scaleY  = sCTM.d;

    var cx=parseFloat(ellipse.getAttribute("cx"))
    var cy=parseFloat(ellipse.getAttribute("cy"))

    var rx=parseFloat(ellipse.getAttribute("rx"))
    var ry=parseFloat(ellipse.getAttribute("ry"))

    var mySVGPointC = svg.createSVGPoint();
    mySVGPointC.x = cx
    mySVGPointC.y = cy
    mySVGPointTransC = mySVGPointC.matrixTransform(sCTM)
    ellipse.setAttribute("cx",mySVGPointTransC.x)
    ellipse.setAttribute("cy",mySVGPointTransC.y)

    ellipse.setAttribute("rx",rx*scaleX)
    ellipse.setAttribute("ry",ry*scaleY)

    //---force removal of transform--
    ellipse.setAttribute("transform","")
    ellipse.removeAttribute("transform")
}
function screenRect(rect,svg)
{
    var sCTM = rect.getCTM()
    var scaleX  = sCTM.a;
    var scaleY  = sCTM.d;

    var x=parseFloat(rect.getAttribute("x"))
    var y=parseFloat(rect.getAttribute("y"))

    var width=parseFloat(rect.getAttribute("width"))
    var height=parseFloat(rect.getAttribute("height"))

    var mySVGPoint = svg.createSVGPoint();
    mySVGPoint.x = x
    mySVGPoint.y = y
    mySVGPointTrans = mySVGPoint.matrixTransform(sCTM)
    rect.setAttribute("x",mySVGPointTrans.x)
    rect.setAttribute("y",mySVGPointTrans.y)

    rect.setAttribute("width",width*scaleX)
    rect.setAttribute("height",height*scaleY)

    //---force removal of transform--
    rect.setAttribute("transform","")
    rect.removeAttribute("transform")
}
function screenPolyline(myPoly,svg)
{
    var sCTM = myPoly.getCTM()
    var pointsList = myPoly.points;
    var n = pointsList.numberOfItems;
    for(var m=0;m<n;m++)
    {
        var mySVGPoint = mySVG.createSVGPoint();
        mySVGPoint.x = pointsList.getItem(m).x
        mySVGPoint.y = pointsList.getItem(m).y
        mySVGPointTrans = mySVGPoint.matrixTransform(sCTM)
        pointsList.getItem(m).x=mySVGPointTrans.x
        pointsList.getItem(m).y=mySVGPointTrans.y
    }
    //---force removal of transform--
    myPoly.setAttribute("transform","")
    myPoly.removeAttribute("transform")
}

function screenPath(path,svg)
{
    var sCTM = path.getCTM()
    var scaleX  = sCTM.a;
    var scaleY  = sCTM.d;

    var segList=path.pathSegList
    var segs=segList.numberOfItems
    //---change segObj values
    for(var k=0;k<segs;k++)
    {
        var segObj=segList.getItem(k)

        if(segObj.x && segObj.y )
        {
            var mySVGPoint = svg.createSVGPoint();
            mySVGPoint.x = segObj.x
            mySVGPoint.y = segObj.y
            mySVGPointTrans = mySVGPoint.matrixTransform(sCTM)
            segObj.x=mySVGPointTrans.x
            segObj.y=mySVGPointTrans.y
        }

        if(segObj.x1 && segObj.y1)
        {
            var mySVGPoint1 = svg.createSVGPoint();
            mySVGPoint1.x = segObj.x1
            mySVGPoint1.y = segObj.y1
            mySVGPointTrans1 = mySVGPoint1.matrixTransform(sCTM)
            segObj.x1=mySVGPointTrans1.x
            segObj.y1=mySVGPointTrans1.y
        }
        if(segObj.x2 && segObj.y2)
        {
            var mySVGPoint2 = svg.createSVGPoint();
            mySVGPoint2.x = segObj.x2
            mySVGPoint2.y = segObj.y2
            mySVGPointTrans2 = mySVGPoint2.matrixTransform(sCTM)
            segObj.x2=mySVGPointTrans2.x
            segObj.y2=mySVGPointTrans2.y
        }

        if(segObj.r1)segObj.r1=segObj.r1*scaleX
        if(segObj.r2)segObj.r2=segObj.r2*scaleX
    }
    //---force removal of transform--
    path.setAttribute("transform","")
    path.removeAttribute("transform")
}

//---changes all transformed points to screen points---
function screenPolygon(myPoly,mySVG)
{
    var sCTM = myPoly.getCTM()
    var pointsList = myPoly.points;
    var n = pointsList.numberOfItems;
    for(var m=0;m<n;m++)
    {
        var mySVGPoint = mySVG.createSVGPoint();
        mySVGPoint.x = pointsList.getItem(m).x
        mySVGPoint.y = pointsList.getItem(m).y
        mySVGPointTrans = mySVGPoint.matrixTransform(sCTM)
        pointsList.getItem(m).x=mySVGPointTrans.x
        pointsList.getItem(m).y=mySVGPointTrans.y
    }
    //---force removal of transform--
    myPoly.setAttribute("transform","")
    myPoly.removeAttribute("transform")
}
```